# How to do conditional formatting of a column in python dataframe and transfer it to excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

How to perform conditional formatting on column Util% in pandas dataframe using python and transfer the data to excel and the highlighted cells should be seen in excel?

Green: 0.00% - 49.99%
Yellow: 50.00% - 79.99%
Red: >= 80.00%
Red: inf%

```
df1:
Customer    Code Util %
BlackRock   BFK 
BlackRock   BFK 
BlackRock   BFK 
BlackRock   BFK 0.12%
BlackRock   BFK 0.00%
        
Ohio        OPS 
Ohio        OPS 18.75%
        
Fund        CEN 
Fund        CEN 
Fund        CEN 
Fund        CEN 
Fund        CEN 2.47%
Fund        CEN 6.21%
        
Rock        ROS 
Rock        ROS 72.81%
        
Square      SCM 
Square      SCM 25.19%
        
Dwight      DWIG    
Dwight      DWIG 0.00%
Dwight      DWIG 17.61%
        
Millennium  MIC 
Millennium  MIC inf%
Millennium  MIC inf%
```

Tried code:

```
def highlight_rows(col):
    value=col.loc['Util %']
    if value >=0.00 and value <=0.4999:
        color = '#BAFFC9' #Green
    elif value >= 0.50 and value <=0.79999:
        color = 'Yellow' # Green
    elif value >=0.80:
        color = 'Red' # Green
    elif value == inf%:
        color = 'Red' # Green
    else:
        pass
    return ['background-color: {}'.format(color) for r in col]

df.style.apply(highlight_rows)
df.to_excel("report.xlsx")
```

Comment: While I definitely don't know for sure, I think you will need to apply the formatting to the excel cells in excel after loading the data from pandas.  I don't believe the pandas formatting transfers to excel.

Comment: Hi, this might help: https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-produce-beautiful-well-formatted-excel-reports-using-python-fd87146a1e0e